# Verificar se campo select foi alterado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de criar uma função js, para verificar se um campo select do meu form foi alterado. 
Criei a função abaixo para verificar se um input foi alterado e funciona, porém o mesmo não funciona para select.

```
var alterado = false;
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('input').keypress(function(){
      alterado = true;
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
$('#select').change(function(){
    alterado = true;
});
```

O que fiz: eu atrelo uma função `jQuery` que ficará a espionar um determinado elemento especificado pelo id, assim que for alterado a função dentro do `change` será executada.

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigada.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="formaPagamento" id="formaPagamento">
<option value="0">Selecione...</option>
<option value="D">Dinheiro</option>
<option value="C">Cartão</option>
<option value="DC">Dinheiro / Cartão</option>
</select>


var formaPagamento = $("#formaPagamento :selected").val();
if (formaPagamento == "0"){
// NÃO CLICOU
}
```